# Changes in exe.config not reflecting in code

Tags: vb.net, winforms, app-config

In code `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("IsFill")` showing null

but when i open exe.config file manually that key is present in file

den i modify exe.config file using below code

```
Dim configFile As Configuration
                    configFile = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Application.ExecutablePath)
                    configFile.AppSettings.Settings("AppVersion").Value = "1.0.1"
                    configFile.Save()
```

`ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("AppVersion")` value is changed but when i open exe.config manually changes not shows.

means if u modify exe.config file from outside,eg. like u add one more key in exe.config then that new key is not getting in code when i am using below code

```
configFile.AppSettings.Settings("AppVersion").Value
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("AppVersion")
```

---

now u conclude that both files r different - which i open manually & other one i open in code 
but path is same , same file i m opening .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

above error came in only windows7 OS. because windows7 doesnt reflect exe.config value.
after restart or log off it shows reflected value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("section to refresh")
```